# The number of traffic accidents on successive days are independent Poisson random variables with mean 2.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

The number of traffic accidents on successive days are independent Poisson random variables with mean 2.

Find the probability that 3 of the next 5 days have two accidents.

Would I treat this the same as if it asked the probability that 6 accidents occur over the next 5 days? And if not, how should I approach this probability?

This is what I have so far: $$ p(x)= \frac{e^{-10} \cdot 10^x}{x!}$$

Comment: What this problem is asking for is the probability that there will be exactly two accidents on 3 of the next 5 days. This is not the same as saying 6 over the next five days. Saying that there is going to be 2 accidents on three of the next five days does not mean that only 6 accidents will occur, it just means that on three of the next five days 2 accidents must occur and for the other two days anything can happen. For example days 1, 2, and 3 could have 2 accidents but days 5 and 6 could each have 45 accidents.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the clarification. Any idea how to calculate specifically two accidents occurring on 3 out of the next 5 days?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see a problem that says something like "k times out of the next n days" you should probably think that the binomial distribution is going to come in to play.

First let $Y \text{~Poi}(2)$, which is the random variable that represents the number of accidents per day, and let $X \text{~Bin}(5,p)$ where $X$ is the random variable that represents the number of days out of the next 5 days that we have two accidents in one day.

We need to find $p$  for $X$ which is the probability of success. A success is that there is 2 accidents in one day so this must mean that $p = P(Y=2) = \dfrac{e^{-2}\cdot2^2}{2!}$.

Now we want to find $ P(X=3) = {5 \choose 3}p^3(1-p)^2$